# Change background button2 into button1 iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa, button

I am a beginner in Xcode, and I have a problem.
I have 2 buttons:

```
- (IBAction) HIGH1: (id) sender
- (IBAction) HIGH2: (id) sender
```

When the user clicks the `HIGH1`button, I want to change the background (with image) of the button `HIGH2`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create IBOutlet for the buttons to change them.

Control+drag the buttons from Interface Builder to the .h file to create the outlets. Something like this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *HIGH1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *HIGH2;
//Dont forget to @synthesize
```

On the IBAction method you then call:

```
- (IBAction) HIGH1: (id) sender
{
    self.HIGH2 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myButtonImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Make sure you have an image with the name you choose in your application bundle, and that the IBOutlet to the buttons is properly connected (The gray circle on the left size of the IBOutlet must have a small black circle inside it)

Comment: No problem, any question please ask.

Answer (score 1):

```
[HIGH1 addTarget:self
          action:@selector(buttonDidPushed)
forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

then,

```
-(void)buttonDidPushed
{
       HIGH2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
       [self.view addSubview:HIGH2];
}
```

I hope this code help you.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I want to put a background image

Comment: That means"HIGH2.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:(UIImage *)myBackgroundImage];" ?

Comment: @user1809759: It is the correct solution, assuming that your button isn't a “system button” (as the docs put it, whatever that means) and you have an image to put in it. If it “doesn't work”, then you should elaborate on what problem you had with it.

Answer (score 0):

access your ivar from HIGH2 and set setBackgroundImage:forState: on HIGH1